# What are the Yesod system requirements?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm currently looking for a VPS to deploy a Yesod site on, I was wondering what the system requirements are for running Yesod? I will be using Nginx with Warp as the system configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no hard-and-fast rules here, but I comfortably run about 5 Yesod-powered sites with Nginx and PostgreSQL and a micro EC2 instance (micro being the instance size, not a random adjective).

Comment: What are the specs of a Tiny instance, I can't find them on the Amazon EC2 website or did you mean micro?

Comment: Doh, sorry, I meant micro, yes.

Comment: @JoostvanDoorn Micro Instance has 613 MB of memory, up to 2 ECUs (for short periodic bursts), EBS storage only, 32-bit or 64-bit platform. See http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#instance

Answer (score 3):

I had a VPS and I had trouble with the glibc version, mainly because a lot of hosting companies are quite conservative and don't offer the latest and greatest versions of the common Linux distributions. GHC won't work with older versions of glibc, although I haven't found anywhere an exact definition of how old is too old.

So one system requirement is: a recent Linux that doesn't have an ancient version of glibc.

Answer (score 3):

I currently run one yesod app on Debian Lenny on VDS, with 500MHz CPU and 196Mb RAM. I do not compile app on the VDS, instead I upload compiled binary. It only needs recent libgmp, but I put one (libgmp*.so) from my desktop to the same directory as application and run

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./my-yesod-app

Comment: So it seems it should be able to run Yesod on almost anything.